# User Data not running command in MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am using USER DATA to launch an instance and install mysql.
Mysql is working fine with my script but issue is that I cant get into the mysql with this script.
As I have to go into the mysql to create new user but my script is working till the installation on mysql, not creating new user. Can anyone tell me do I need to add some special character with the Mysql commands?

```
!Base64 |
     #!/bin/bash
     sudo apt update
     sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client -y
     sudo mysql
     CREATE USER 'aadi'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by 'aadibhatti';
```

Comment: maybe you can take a hint from https://gist.github.com/sheikhwaqas/9088872

Answer (score 0):

User Data scripts are run as `root` user. Therefore, **do not use `sudo`** in the scripts.

Also, the User Data script will wait for `mysql` to exit before continuing with the commands, so you will need to pass your SQL using `mysql -e`, such as:

```
mysql -u root -p somedb -e "CREATE USER 'aadi'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by 'aadibhatti';"
```

See: [Run a single MySQL query from the command line | The Electric Toolbox Blog](https://electrictoolbox.com/run-single-mysql-query-command-line/)